# What causes an object placed on the inner wall of a spinning cone to move up the wall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centrifugal-force

[image]

I'm maddeningly confused about this problem conceptually. The solutions manual says that if the angular velocity is large enough, the mass will move up the wall of the cone. I can't convince myself of this. There are only three forces on the mass: the normal force of the cone wall, the friction force between the wall and the mass, and gravity. Friction doesn't come into play until another force tries to accelerate the mass, so I'll ignore it for now. Gravity has a component along the cone wall, but it is always "downward". The normal force is always perpendicular to the wall, so it never has any component along the wall. So why would the mass ever start moving upward along the wall?!

I understand that inertia/centrifugal force is what keeps the mass pressed against the wall (given large enough velocity). But it doesn't seem to me like inertia would make the mass move up along the cone without help from some other force, but I see no such force.

Edit: To clarify what I meant by "conceptual", here's what I'm asking. Suppose you and I are looking at the cone from a ways off. And I notice the mass start to move upward as the cone reaches a certain angular speed. I say "We're in an inertial reference frame, where Newton's second law is F = ma. So what's the force making the mass accelerate in that direction?" What do you answer? If you say "the normal force" that makes no sense to me, since the normal force has no components along the wall. If you say "gravity", that also makes no sense, since gravity's component along the wall points down the wall, not up it.

Comment: *.I can't convince myself of this.* Have you tried doing any calculations?

Comment: The inertial force is not normal to the wall.

Comment: Are you familiar with [free-body diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_body_diagram)? Incorporating rotational acceleration into such diagrams in the frame of the spinning object?

Comment: Simplify the problem a bit. Consider a cone made of ice so there is no friction. It will work the same if you spin the mass around. This tells you you are right to ignore friction.

Comment: Consider another similar problem. Instead of a cone, suppose you are sitting on a flat plate like a merry go round. Keep friction or ignore it as you choose. Does it make sense that you would move outward? Suppose the flat plate is a very shallow cone, tilted 1$^o$ or so. Does it make sense that you would fly outward and a little up?

Comment: Consider a counter example. Make the cone very steep. Make it a cylinder where you sit on the inside surface. As you spin around, you will feel an outward force that pushes you into the surface of the cylinder. Do you think you would move outward then? Would gravity slide you downward?

Answer (score 0):

If you assume no friction, the x-component of the normal force must be $\frac{mv^2}{r}$ to keep it in circular motion.

Thus the total normal force will be $F_N = \frac{mv^2}{r}\frac{1}{\cos\theta}$, **because the normal force can only act perpendicular to the surface** (if you talk about this as a "conceptual problem" this is the one concept not to miss).

The amount in the y-direction is therefore $F_{Ny} = \frac{mv^2}{r}\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac{mv^2}{r}\tan\theta.$

So we have as our total forces in the y direction $\Sigma F_{y} = \frac{mv^2}{r}\tan\theta - mg$.

So whichever of those two is bigger determines whether the object slides up or down the cone.

Comment: To clarify what I meant by "conceptual": Suppose you and I are looking at the cone from a ways off. And I notice the mass start to move upward as the cone reaches a certain angular speed. I say "We're in an inertial reference frame, where Newton's second law is F = ma. So what's the force making the mass accelerate in that direction?" What do you answer? If you say "the normal force" that makes no sense to me, since the normal force has no components along the wall. If you say "gravity", that also makes no sense, since gravity's component along the wall points down the wall, not up it.

Comment: I think I'm starting to see my issue. I'm assuming the force that moves the mass up the wall is either the normal force or gravity, but really it is the net resultant of the two, i.e. the sum of the normal force and the negative of the weight has a component upwards along the wall.

Comment: Provided the normal force is large enough. Otherwise that component is downward along the wall.

Comment: Correct, you can't point to one force or the other as being solely responsible for its outward/inward movement. You also have to remember this is not a statics problem from the lab frame. And from the rotating frame you must add the centrifugal frame that is responsible for the outward motion.

Answer (score 0):

When the cone is rotating not too fast, and the body doesn't slide, the sum of the forces equals the centripetal acceleration. That means: the net force is horizontal and directed to the axis of the cone. It is only possible if the Normal force increases and the static **upward** friction force decreases compared to a situation without rotation (because $m\mathbf g$ doesn't change).

If the rotation increases further, the static friction eventually go to zero, and any further angular velocity results in a static friction **downward** along the incline, while the body stays at its position, rotating with the cone.

When the static friction is not enough to hold the centripetal acceleration, the body slides following the tangent to the circle where it is located in the cone. And it is only possible moving to a greater radius, upward in the cone. It doesn't go upward due to a force, but because it follows the inertial tangential path.

Note that all that effect requires friction. Without it, the rotation of the cone is not transmitted to the object, and it simple accelerates downward along the incline, due to the component of $m\mathbf g$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of the [car on a banked track](https://onlyphysics.org/mit-problem-set-3-circular-motion-question-2/) situation.

[image]

Diagram **a** shows the FBD for no rotation and the mass not slipping down the track.

Applying Newton's second law in the vertical direction, $N\cos \theta + f\sin \theta - mg =0$ **(i)**, and the horizontal direction, $N\sin \theta -f\cos \theta = 0$ **(ii)**.

As the cone starts to rotate there must be a net force in the x-direction to produce the centripetal acceleration.

$N\sin \theta -f\cos \theta = m\,r\,\omega^2$ with the magnitude of the normal force $N$ increasing which results in a net force in the x-direction, equation **(ii)**, whilst at the same time the frictional force, $f$, must have decreased to keep the net force in the y direction zero, $N\color{red}\uparrow \cos \theta + f\color{red} \downarrow\sin \theta - mg =0$.

As the angular velocity, \omega$ increases there come a time when $f=0$ which is illustrated in diagram **a**.
This corresponds to the "ideal" banking angle for a given speed of a car on a banked track.

Increasing the angular speed still further means that the friction force now has to be directed downwards as in diagram **c**.
Vertical direction, $N\cos \theta - f\sin \theta - mg =0$ **(iii)**
Horizontal direction, $N\sin \theta +f\cos \theta = mr\omega^2$ **(iv)**.

However the frictional force has an upper limit $f \le \mu_{\rm static}N$ and so if the cone is rotating fast enough there is a resultant force upwards resulting in the mass moving upwards.

*The normal force is always perpendicular to the wall, so it never has any component along the wall.*
Very true but there is a vertical component of the normal force which causes an upward acceleration.
In terms of infinitesimals.
The net upward force makes the mass move upward and lose contact with the cone.
However the mass has a tangential velocity which means that it makes contact with the cone a little further up (at a greater radius of rotation) and the process repeats itself with the mass "climbing" out of the cone and possibly to a new dynamic equilibrium position.